# centos 7 pg function with .pgpass from sh file

Tags: centos, bash, centos7, postgresql

I'm trying to run a postgreSQL function from a `.sh` file but it keep asking the password.

The password is under password protection and I'm using `.pgpass` to connect, I'm already using `pg_dump` in this way and it works perfectly, no need to insert the password.

```
DBNAME2=mydb
su postgres -c "pg_dump -w -c -U bcuser $DBNAME -Fc > /tmp/dbbackup.dump"
```

my problem now is that I want to do something like this

```
sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d $DBNAME2 -c "select * from removeunuseduser()"
```

my `.pgpass` is located in `/var/lib/pgsql`, I'm using Centos 7 and PG 9.3
but without needs to insert the password.

UPDATE

I was taking a look into this question but nothing of that seems to work, of course if I use `PGPASSWORD=mypsw` it works but I would like to avoid to use that

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223665/postgresql-query-from-bash-script-as-database-user-postgres

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -i -u postgres ...`?

Comment: still asking for the password, I've updated my question with what I've already tried